# Invoke-Expression: testing for all potential code injection possibilities

Tags: powershell, code-injection

I am looking to define some complex conditional statements in XML, since I now have 20 different conditions I need to test, and I could well need to add more, and I would rather add those conditions by providing an updated XML file rather than issuing revised code. For what it's worth, I am trying to identify correct Autodesk Uninstall strings because Autodesk doesn't follow Windows standards at all. Their new installers will have their own special uninstall that uses their ODIS executable, while also having a bunch of standard MSIExec based uninstalls that do nothing and/or cause errors. I am trying to parse all the Uninstalls and filter out just the ones that work right. And they are VERY inconsistent, thus 20 different conditions at this point.
So what I have is a `$rawKeys` variable that contains all the keys from the Uninstall key in the registry, and I loop through all of them and do some comparisons and adding anything that meets the skip criteria to a `$skip` variable so when I encounter that later in the loop I can just skip over it.
So...
An example of a conditional that identifies a particular Autodesk Uninstall that has invalid uninstalls keys as well looks like this.

```
if ($key.guid -and ($key.publisher -like 'Autodesk*') -and ($key.uninstallString -like '*AdODIS*') -and
   ($skip = $rawKeys.Where({$_.guid -and ($_.publisher -like 'Autodesk*') -and ($_.displayName -eq $key.displayName) -and ( $_.uninstallString)}))) {
```

In moving that data to XML I have

```
<Pattern>
        <Find>
            <Criteria property="$key.guid" operator="-eq" value="exists" />
            <Criteria property="$key.publisher" operator="-like" value="Autodesk*" />
            <Criteria property="$key.uninstallString" operator="-like" value="*AdODIS*" />
        </Find>
        <Skip>
            <Criteria property="$PSItem.guid" operator="-eq" value="exists" />
            <Criteria property="$PSItem.publisher" operator="-like" value="Autodesk*" />
            <Criteria property="$PSItem.displayName" operator="-eq" value="$key.displayName" />
            <Criteria property="$PSItem.uninstallString" operator="-eq" value="exists" />
        </Skip>
    </Pattern>
```

And I have verified that I can use `Invoke-Expression` to extract correct data from the variable/Xml. The validation there is simply

```
$hash = @{
    one = '1'
    two = '2'
}
$string = '$hash.two'
Invoke-Expression $string
```

Which correctly produces `2`

But of course `Invoke-Expression` is at risk of malicious code injection, which can be seen with

```
$string = '$hash.two; Write-Host'
```

I have done some searching and every post I find specifically mentions injecting code using the command separator `;`. And my good data will never have a semi-colon, so a first line of defense would seem to be simply to look for a semi colon and if found throw an exception. But a malicious actor could also simply replace the entire value like this

```
$string = 'Write-Host "Malicious Code"'
```

Given that my good values will never contain a space, I could search for space and thus catch any Cmdlet with arguments.
And finally, the malicious code could be just a Cmdlet, so I could use

```
Get-Command $string
```

and only `Invoke-Expression` on a failure.

I THINK that covers all bases, but I have yet to find someone who offers a definitive "Safe parsing of strings before Invoke-Expression" example, and I would really like to be more certain that I really have covered all bases.
That, or be convinced that this is such a bad idea that I should simply keep all the conditionals in code and provide updates in new, signed PSM1s.

Another option I am looking at is to sign the XML and test that at XML load. If the XML has been changed in any way I throw an error. I suspect that is an additional layer of security, not a replacement for the in code validations mentioned above.

EDIT: Sigh. It seems I do have a scenario with a space.

```
$_.uninstallString -eq "MsiExec.exe /X$($_.guid)")
```

But, if I wrap the variables in `$()` as shown here, in the XML, then

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($string)
```

will expand things appropriately. And from there, since I will never use the expanded data for execution, only for string comparisons, I am safe. I THINK. :)

Comment: But still [Avoid using Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/avoid-using-invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.2).  Is there not another way to solve this?  (I know I should not ask questions in a comment, but ..... )

Comment: @luuk That was definitely on my mind, as my impression is that there are very few situations where there really is no other better option. And after I posted I reframed my search a bit and came across `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()`, and in my case that looks like the better answer.

Comment: `ExpandString()` is still susceptible to script injection, as `$()` expressions allows to run arbitrary commands: `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString("$(Remove-Item foo23bar42)")`. A safer alternative is to use `$sb = [scriptblock]::Create($expression)` and then call `$sb.CheckRestrictedLanguage(...)` to restrict what the scriptblock can do. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.checkrestrictedlanguage?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0

Comment: Taking a step back, is there a difference between how you’d ship a new xml “rules” file vs an updated script? Unless there’s a really compelling reason, I’d imagine it’d be easier to maintain 20 hard-codes “if” commands in a separate Powershell function rather than an “inner system” rules engine. It might be controversial, but I think simple repetition is *sometimes* better than a complex DRY solution :-)

Comment: @ zett42 Aha, I though $() only expanded strings, not that it worked like an inline code execution. But that's silly, since I know I can include Cmdlets in a string that way. Gotta do some more research.

Comment: @mclayton I think the main things is that I have multiple modules and a sign and zip them all at once. And the "upgrade" process is to unzip and replace all the files. So more overhead compared to signing a single Xml and making it available for download. I am hoping I have found all of Autodesk's #%$^-ups, but it's Autodesk and given time, the will find a new pooch to screw. They just can't help themselves.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you are building the xml like this.  Why not just something without the variables coded in the xml `<Criteria property="guid" operator="-eq" value="exists" />` and then work with the property name only on your objects in the code?

Comment: @Daniel Because there is a mix of conditions. Usually I can assume all the Skip stuff is `$PSitem` for the property, but not always. For example `$skip = $rawKeys.Where({($_.guid -and (($_.displayName -eq ($key.displayName -replace ' Autodesk', $Null)) -and (($key.displayName -replace ' Autodesk', $Null) -ne $key.displayName)) -and ($_.uninstallString -eq "MsiExec.exe /X$($_.guid)"))}))`

Comment: Another way to look at it is this: If you’re signing the xml file then *that’s* where you need to validate the contents, not when you come to consuming it. Signing it is basically saying “I trust the contents of this file, and you should too”. If the contents of the file are untrustworthy you shouldn’t be signing it…

Comment: @mclayton True dat! ^^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noted, `Invoke-Expression` should only be used under controlled conditions, it should be avoided when the expression can be provided by users, as  it is susceptible to script injection. The same can be said about `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()`. The latter can be exploited by use of the [subexpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--) `$(…)` operator, which can run arbitrary commands.

A safe way (to my knowledge) for preventing script injection through user-defined expressions, is the [`ScriptBlock.CheckRestrictedLanguage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.checkrestrictedlanguage?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) method.

Here is a simplified example:

```sh
# Variables to be used in the scriptblock
$a = 23; $b = 42

# Create a scriptblock, which could be user input, which is not executed yet.
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create('$a -lt $b')

# Define restrictions for the scriptblock
$allowedCommands  = [string[]] @()          # no allowed commands
$allowedVariables = [string[]] @('a', 'b')  # only these variables can be used
$allowEnvVars     = $false                  # environment variables not allowed

# Check the scriptblock against the restrictions
# This throws an exception if the scriptblock doesn't comply to the restrictions.
$sb.CheckRestrictedLanguage( $allowedCommands, $allowedVariables, $allowEnvVars )

# If we reach here, executing the scriptblock is safe.
& $sb
```

The above code *runs successfully*, as the expression `$a -lt $b` only uses the allowed variables and doesn't call any command.

Here are some examples that would cause the script to *terminate with an error*, because of the restrictions we have defined:

```sh
$a -lt $x         # invalid variable x - only a and b are allowed
$env:SystemRoot   # environment variables are not allowed
Write-Host 42     # commands are not allowed
.\SomeScript.ps1  # commands are not allowed
```

Comment: Woot! I think this is the comprehensive answer for actual safe use of `Invoke-Expression`/`&` that I THOUGHT I was looking for. And I think for my actual immediate need, to expand variables in a string without execution, I can use `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()` along with a signed XML as mentioned by @mclayton. So I learned another way to avoid `Invoke-Expression` and how to use it safely. Very productive thread. :)

Comment: @Gordon You might add your signing solution as another answer.

Comment: One detail I wonder about. It appears that `CheckRestrictedLanguage()` will fail on any use of properties, even on allowed variables. Am I understanding that right? It's not the end of the world. I can assign straight variables values from properties, and use that in my validation, but I want to make sure I am not missing a way to include properties.

Comment: As for adding the signed XML as an answer, it wasn't my answer really. I considered it an "extra". @mclayton pointed out that I can/should trust my own signed XML. Plus that's not like yours, an answer to the actual question. It's more pointing out that my question wasn't really the right question vis-a-vis the problem I was trying to solve. :)

Comment: Re properties with `CheckRestrictedLanguage()` - interesting, I didn't knew that. This seems to be a general restriction that is applied, regardless of the arguments supplied to the function.